# Tensorflow Java API on Spark fails at new Graph()

Tags: java, apache-spark, tensorflow

I'm running the Java API of Tensorflow (version 1.8) to evaluate an already trained model on Spark. However, when the code reaches to this command `Graph gr = new Graph()` the code fails, most of the time, and sometimes it goes through.

This happens both on executors and on the Driver, even if `Graph gr= new Graph()` is the only TensorFlow command I keep. Using Try-Catch wasn't useful, as when the it reaches this line, the executor fails and exits.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Could you include [mcve] and traceback?

Comment: Without a stack trace it's impossible to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

We figured what is the issue:
The Java API of tensorflow has dependency on Visual C++ redistribution. When we run it on Spark some of the machines miss the dependency *.dlls. This causes JVM crash.